# @user.reload not working as expected (change the year to 2000)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Hi I`m following the Michael Hartl tutorial and I came across strange behaviour.

In chapter 12 Password reset, password_reset_controller, create action looks like this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase) 
    if @user     
      @user.create_reset_digest   
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = 'Email sent with password reset instructions'    
      redirect_to root_url       
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Email address not found'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And the create_reset_digest method looks like this:

```
def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
end
```

I used a byebug to monitor changes and came across a strange thing:

When I try byebug at the end of the create action I got this result:

```
 #<User id: 762146111, ..., reset_sent_at: 2016-11-11 13:47:00 UTC>
```

But when I try to see what was saved after @user.reload, I get:

```
#<User id: 762146111, ..., reset_sent_at: "2000-01-01 13:47:00">
```

Why is the attribute reser_sent_at switching to year 2000-01-01?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `to_datetime` in

```
update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now.to_datetime)
```

in your `create_reset_digest`

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. I even tried look at db:schema and it has, sent_at attrbute set as time >> `t.time     "reset_sent_at"`

Comment: you need to make migration and change attribute `time` to `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the time you are saving to **Time.now**

def create_reset_digest
        self.reset_token = User.new_token
        update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
        update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.now)
    end